# Stuck in a Thévenin's Theorem exercise

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, thevenin

I'm practicing applying Thévenin's Theorem, and I'm struggling with computing \$R_{th}\$ in the following circuit:

[image]

---

**My attempt:** after removing voltage and current sources, and combining resistors in series, I get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsUAdg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

- I can disregard \$R_6\$, right?
- Can I treat \$R_1+R_2\$ and \$R_4\$ as resistors in series? The fact that node \$A\$ lies between them makes me unsure.
- Regardless of the answer to the previous questions, could I get a hint as to how to continue?

Comment: You did a good job so far. Yes, you can disregard R6 and R7+R8 as well. Try to place a "virtual voltage source" between the A and B terminals and try to find the current path and the total current draw from a "virtual source". And it should be clear to you that R1+R2 are in parallel with R5+R4.

Comment: Wait, why can I disregard \$R_7+R_8\$?

Comment: What happened to R3?

Comment: You can disregard R7+ R8 because they are shorted.

Comment: @Andyaka OP wants to finds the current and the voltage across R3 using Thevenins Theorem.

Comment: @G36 Why are \$R_7\$ and \$R_8\$ shorted?

Comment: Originally R7 + R8 were connected directly across V1 voltage source. And we turn off the V1 voltage source to find Rth resistance. Thus, we shorted out the together the lower and the upper terminal of the resistors.  And this is why we can ignore R7 and R8.

Comment: @G36 I'm truly sorry, but I struggle to understand that argument. That being said, could I argue as follows?: let \$I\$ be the current flowing through \$R_5\$ from right to left. At the node, we may apply a current divider, which immediately tells us that no current flows through the \$R_7+R_8\$ resistors. As no current flows through them, we can disregard them.

Comment: @G36 how are you able to say that. I see nothing in the post that says that. So, what happened to R3?

Comment: @G36 Sorry, I should have stated it, but it is true.

Comment: "Why are R7 and R8 shorted?" You drew them that way, see your second diagram.  Both ends are directly connected.

Comment: @Sam R1 and R2 are in series, combine them (2k) and then take that in parallel with R3 and combine them (RX=1k). Meanwhile, V1 shorts out R7+R8, so throw them away as irrelevant. The current source is open so R6 is also thrown out. This leaves R5 in series with R4 to make 1.5k. That 1.5k is in parallel with RX. So 600 Ohms total for the Thevenin resistance seen at A with B grounded. You are done.